# Is there a way to find out which array the image belongs to, after loading it into an array in preload() function? - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, p5.js

I am trying to load multiple images from multiple folders in three different arrays like so:

```
function preload() 
{

for (let num=0; num<10; num++){

    array1[num] = loadImage('first/img'+ num +'.png');
  }
   
  for (let num1=0; num1<18; num1++){

    array2[num1] = loadImage('second/img'+ num1 +'.png');
  } 

  for (let num2=0; num2<25; num2++){

    array3[num2] = loadImage('third/img'+ num2 +'.png');
  }  
}
```

Now I want to pick a random image from a random folder. If the image belongs to array1, I want to print 'first folder'. If second, it should print 'second folder' and so on.

Is there any easier way to get this task done?

Comment: I believe your main issue is the way you are storing the images, a proper approach could be to store the images into an array of objects and add to them a folder property ('folder' in the next example), something like: 
[
 { image: loadImage(path), folder: 'first' ,
 { image: loadImage(path), folder: 'second',
 ...
] 

At this way you would be able to select a random image and also to have a better control over them

Answer (score 0):

You can pick a random folder first, then pick a random image from it.
This is the pseudo code.

```js
const getRand = (num) => parseInt(Math.random() * num);

const folder1 = Array.from(Array(10).keys());
const folder2 = Array.from(Array(18).keys());
const folder3 = Array.from(Array(25).keys());
const allItems = [folder1, folder2, folder3];

const randInt1 = getRand(allItems.length);
const randomFolder = allItems[randInt1];
const randInt2 = getRand(randomFolder.length);
const randomImage = randomFolder[randInt2];
```